# посчитать количество гласных букв в строке SQL

Tags: sql

подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь посчитать количество согласных букв в строке SQL и все работает ок. когда хочу посчитать количество гласных, убрав знак ^ в регулярке - получаю какой-то кривой результат.  в чем может быть дело?

```
SELECT name, count(pattern)
FROM (
SELECT *,
       regexp_matches(name,'([^аеиуэыюяо])','g') as pattern
FROM Personal ) test
GROUP BY name
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pqn7HUneeB2kr8DT9hQEAt/1

Comment: Ну вы приведите конкретные примеры в вопросе, чтобы был предмет для разговора

Answer (score 0):

было найдено более элегантное решение вопроса:

```
SELECT name,
      REGEXP_COUNT (name, 'ё|у|е|ы|а|о|э|я|и|ю', 1, 'i') as count
FROM Personal
```